# Checking and unchecking UITableViewCells with a click of a UIToolBarButton

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview, nsindexpath

**How can you put a checkmark beside all the cells and remove the checkmark with a click of a `UIToolBarButton`? Is this possible?**

I have tried to iterate through the number of cells loading in the tableview but I don't know how to set the accessorytype to checkmark for all of them and then back to none when all of them are checked?

Comment: Just to let you know, I wrote an IBAction and linked it to the toolbarbutton. Using the for loop I counted the number of cells in the tableview loaded on the screen but the problem is I dont know how to set the indexPath to each of them and then set the cell.accessorytype property to checkmark or none.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't change the cells directly -- change the data that's used to populate the cells, and then tell the table to reload it's data.

So, you'll need the following:

- a way to store represent the 'checked state' in the data that the cells represent;
- a way to set the accessory for a single cell in your `-tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` method according to the value of the 'checked state' for the item that the cell in question represents

For a normal UITableViewCell, you can set the accessory by saying something like:

```
cell.accessoryType = item.isChecked ? UITableViewAccessoryCheckmark : UITableViewAccessoryNone;
```

Comment: Caleb I get your point. The situation is pretty complex here. I am doing the checking and unchecking(i.e. the accessory on a single click changes to checked and if its checked already it becomes unchecked and vice-versa) in the cellForRowAtIndexPath method..

Could I write a separate function where I could iterate through whole of my tableview and without getting the checked state(because it doesnt matter to me if its checked or no), just uncheck all of them..

Comment: Again, no, you don't want "iterate through the table." You want to iterate through the data that's represented by the table. In most cases, the table only contains the cells that you can see -- cells that scroll off one end are recycled and used for cells that are about to scroll on from the other. If you try to set some state for a given row by changing the cell, that change will be forgotten as soon as the cell is no longer visible. If you change your data and let that drive the appearance of the cells your changes will be remembered properly.

Comment: First, I dont get you are trying to say here if you change your data and.. I am pretty sure I need not change my data to do a mere simple accessoryType change as I am not saving any of this data anywhere. 
Second, I am pretty sure you didn't understand my case. Sir, I am not trying to be rude in any case possible. Its just that I am fairly new to iPhone programming.

Comment: Steps I need to accomplish - psuedo code
1.-(IBAction) reset{
 (for all the cells in the tableview){
     set the accessorytype to None
  }

2. -(IBAction)SelectAll{
      (for all the cells in the tableview){
     set the accessorytype to checkMark
  }

Thats all I want. If you could help me with that, it would be really nice of you. Thank you for your time :)

Comment: How do you know what to put in each cell? Usually, there's an array or similar structure that contains the items represented in the table. If you have that, that's where you want to store the checked/unchecked state of the row. If your table contains only static cells (cell content determined by data built into the code) you may need to create an array to store the checked/unchecked state . If you're still stuck, try posting some code, such as your `-tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:`.

Comment: Okay, let me explain the whole thing to you - I have a WCF REST webservice which emits JSON output. All the data loaded in the tableview is coming from that JSON output. So depending on the option you clicked in the previous view it loads a different MutableArray in the tableview. As this is a first loadup(Currently I am working on) so there is nothing checked. So all the cells have the accessorytype as none. Yes I know I have to save the checked/unchecked state in an array coming from that JSON but for right now I am not worrying about it.

Comment: I just want to select all rows and deselect all rows (GUI) -- just on the GUI for the user. I dont know if it explains you the stuff, but if you have any questions just shoot! 

Thank you.

Comment: For a more clear Idea, I want an alternative to this - (UITableViewCellAccessoryType)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView accessoryTypeForRowWithIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

 return UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;
}

The only difference is that I cant hook this up to my toolbar button and this loads the tableview with every cell having a checkMark.. I want the same functionality but in a simple IBAction button which I can manipulate or adjust later when my app is at some next level.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
    for(UITableViewCell* cell in tableAlert.tableView.visibleCells){
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryChecked;
    }
```

You also need to update your data set so that when you scroll the cells get the correct accessory in cellForRow.